# Why is my for loop not looping the elements right?

Tags: go, variadic-functions, goroutine

Starting from gobyexample for variadic functions and WaitGroup, I came up with this to run a number of functions as goroutines in parallel and synchronize (prints are debug only):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func WaitForFuncs(funcs ...func()) {
  fmt.Print("funcs are: ", funcs, "\n")
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  for _, f := range funcs {
    fmt.Print("f is: ", f, "\n")
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
      defer wg.Done()
      f()
    }()
  }
  wg.Wait()
}


func main() {
    num := 4
    WaitForFuncs(
      func() {
        fmt.Printf("Worker foo starting, num=%d\n", num)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Printf("Worker foo done\n")
      },
      func() {
        fmt.Printf("Worker bar starting\n")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Printf("Worker bar done\n")
      },
      func() {
        fmt.Printf("Worker baz starting\n")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Printf("Worker baz done\n")
      },
    )
}
```

But the output surprises me:

```
funcs are: [0x4a0360 0x4a0470 0x4a0540]
f is: 0x4a0360
f is: 0x4a0470
f is: 0x4a0540
Worker bar starting
Worker baz starting
Worker baz starting
Worker bar done
Worker baz done
Worker baz done
```

Why does it print `bar baz baz` and not `foo bar baz`?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-reference-to-loop-iterator-variable

Comment: And the bullet point that follows it: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables

Comment: This is not a trace condition, it's the usual gotcha of using the same lool iterator without copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an intermediate variable in the loop, otherwise the value gets overwritten before executed. That is the reason why you only see the last func three times.

```
func waitForFuncs(funcs ...func()) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, f := range funcs {
        intermediate := f
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(inner func()) {
            defer wg.Done()
            inner()
        }(intermediate)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```